# CSV file is skipping to next line in the middle of a row

Tags: python

I am having a weird issue that I just can't figure out, I am attempting to create a simple CSV file in a certain format. It mostly works, but for some reason, every row gets sent to the next line about half-way thru. Also, there are quotes around the `source` entries that shouldn't be there.

Example of CSV:

```
target,source,type,source_followers,source_following
central_insurance_companies,"carolpaul60
",directed,1382,1265
central_insurance_companies,"haif_250
",directed,1382,1265
central_insurance_companies,"hmadvisors
",directed,1382,1265
central_insurance_companies,"speakmanweaver
",directed,1382,1265
```

I am using the following main code:

```
targetFollowers = getFollowerCount() #int
targetFollowing = getFollowingCount() #int
setupCSV()
updateCSV(accountName, targetFollowers, targetFollowing)
```

with the following functions:

```
def setupCSV():
    csvFile = open('edges.csv','w',encoding="utf-8")
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    
    #create header
    csvWriter.writerow(['target','source','type','source_followers','source_following'])
    
    csvFile.close()
```

```
def updateCSV(accountName, targetFollowers, targetFollowing):
    #open followers
    followerFile = open('followerFile.txt','r', encoding="utf-8")
    Lines = followerFile.readlines()
    
    # update rows of csv
    lineCount = 1
    while True:
        sourceName = linecache.getline(r'followerFile.txt', lineCount)
        rowUpdate(accountName, sourceName, targetFollowers, targetFollowing)
        lineCount += 1
        
        # stop loop
        if not sourceName:
            followerFile.close()
            break
    
    #close file
    followerFile.close()
```

```
def rowUpdate(accountName, sourceName, targetFollowers, targetFollowing):
    # row data
    rowData = [accountName, sourceName, 'directed', targetFollowers, targetFollowing]
    
    # write data
    with open('edges.csv','a', encoding="utf-8") as csvFile:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
        csvWriter.writerow(rowData)
        csvFile.close()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your issues are actually the same issue.  The reason why your rows are being pushed to the next line is because your source column values all end in a newline character which when written to a file results in a literal new line.  This is also the reason for the quotes.  The CSV writer detects the newline character so it automatically applies the quotes to the value.

The root cause of the issue looks like it is coming from `linecache.getline(...)`.

According to the [python docs for that function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html?highlight=linecache#linecache.getline)

> the terminating newline character will be included for lines that are found

So in order to avoid passing that newline character into your csv file, probably the simplest way would be to call `sourceName.strip()` before adding the value to your csv file or simply adding `.strip()` to the end of the `getline()` function.

For example:

```
sourceName = linecache.getline(r'followerFile.txt', lineCount).strip()  # <- added .strip() here
rowUpdate(accountName, sourceName, targetFollowers, targetFollowing)
lineCount += 1
```